# Saving file to the file system using different user credentials in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How can I save a file to the file system using a different user than the one i'm currently logged in with ?

I'm currently using .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Different user, or System Account? also, can we assume that you have the credentials needed for the other user?

Comment: Can be done with the WindowsIdentity class, but involves some WinApi calls, so it is not the easiest of tasks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328410/write-files-to-a-location-from-another-user-and-domain

Comment: How complex do you want to make this? There are tons of different ways to pull this off, can you give us more detail on the solution needed?

Comment: @DaveZiegler What is the easiest way which requires minimum code ?

Comment: Seriously, this question requires more detail.

Comment: this question is great, There is no need for more detail. proof: 2369 views (at 23/06/2017).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can impersonate the other users if you have their login credentials

Use DLL Import to call LogonUser in Win32

```cs
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);
```

then you can do the impersonation in your code

```cs
SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;

string userName, domainName, password;

const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, password,
                LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                out safeTokenHandle);
```

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN for [`FileInfo.SetAccessControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.setaccesscontrol.aspx):

> The ACL specified for the `fileSecurity` parameter replaces the existing ACL for the file. To add permissions for a new user, use the [`GetAccessControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c13ttb3.aspx) method to obtain the existing ACL, modify it, and then use `SetAccessControl` to apply it back to the file.

So, given we have a `FileInfo` for the file in question:

```
// FileInfo file = ...;
var acl = file.GetAccessControl();

// Add or Remove access rules on this FileSecurity object
acl.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(
    @"domain\someuser",
    FileSystemRights.FullControl, /* pick something less */
    AccessControlType.Allow));

file.SetAccessControl(acl);
```

Alternatively, if you need to do this prior to saving the file you'll need to use [Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx):

```
// You'd be best served to beg, borrow, and steal the LogonUser
// code from the MSDN article.

using (var identity = new WindowsIdentity(token))
using (var context = identity.Impersonate())
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenText("impersonated.txt"))
    {
        // ... write
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We have an old ASMX web service that runs under a dedicated service account, and our apps send web requests to it. The files are sent to the service as byte arrays, and the service writes the files out to a shared location. You'd want to make sure you have adequate security and logging in place for the apps using this!